# Images not showing correctly on android

Tags: android, delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have an issue with FMX on Android not showing images correctly.

My app, which is my first ever for Android, has a background and a splash image that are shown upon app start. The splash shows on top of everything, and then a timer makes it go away, and show the background.

Screenshot from Memu emulator:

[image]

Screenshot from my phone:

[image]

Source from replicated issue:

http://anbech.me/bgtest/bg_test.zip

I've been coding Pascal since Delphi 6, and I never asked about any coding related issues before this, but this is very new to me.

So far, I've been trying for 3 days to get it working, but without luck.

Currently I'm using `RCDATA` resources and loading images from there. I tried to even have the images on a different form, as other `TImage` components, and load from there. I also notice that if the images are set to `Align=Client`, and `WrapMode=Center`, then they all get misplaced on the `MainForm`, but work great on other forms. So now, I tried cropping the images, which are squares, so they'll have the same aspect ratio as the device it runs on.

I could go on, because what I've tried so far is a long talk.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp, BmpSplash: TBitmap;
  iRect: TRect;
begin
  Load_image_from_resource(Form1.Image_bg, '0_bg');
  Load_image_from_resource(Form1.Image_splash, '0_splash');

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.Width := round(Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap.Width * (Form1.ClientWidth / Form1.ClientHeight));
    Bmp.Height := round(Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap.Height);
    iRect.Width := round(Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap.Width * (Form1.ClientWidth / Form1.ClientHeight));
    iRect.Height := Bmp.Height;
    iRect.Left := round((iRect.Height - iRect.Width) / 2);
    iRect.Top := 0;
    Bmp.CopyFromBitmap(Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap, iRect, 0, 0);
    //Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap := nil;
    Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap.Assign(Bmp);
    Form1.Image_bg.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    Form1.Image_bg.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.Stretch;
  finally
    Bmp.DisposeOf;
    Bmp := nil;
  end;

  BmpSplash := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    BmpSplash.Width := round(Form1.Image_splash.Bitmap.Width * (Form1.ClientWidth / Form1.ClientHeight));
    BmpSplash.Height := round(Form1.Image_splash.Bitmap.Height);
    iRect.Width := round(Form1.Image_splash.Bitmap.Width * (Form1.ClientWidth / Form1.ClientHeight));
    iRect.Height := Bmp.Height;
    iRect.Left := round((iRect.Height - iRect.Width) / 2);
    iRect.Top := 0;
    BmpSplash.CopyFromBitmap(Form1.Image_splash.Bitmap, iRect, 0, 0);
    //Form1.Image_splash.Bitmap := nil;
    Form1.Image_splash.Bitmap.Assign(BmpSplash);
    Form1.Image_splash.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    Form1.Image_splash.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.Stretch;
  finally
    BmpSplash.DisposeOf;
    BmpSplash := nil;
  end;

  Form1.Image_bg.SendToBack;
  Form1.Image_bg.Visible := False;
  Form1.Image_splash.BringToFront;
  Form1.Image_splash.Visible := True;
  Form1.Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Form1.Image_bg.Visible := True;
  Form1.Image_splash.Visible := False;    
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the grammar editing, Remy :-)

Comment: I see a couple of issues with your code, but you have not expressed how exactly you want the splash image and the back image to show in various situations, like horizontal/vertical different display resolutions, etc. Please edit and add information.

Comment: I'm sorry if I haven't been clear enough, I tried not to go into details that much, because otherwise it would've been a whole book for you to read :-)
I want the splash image to show when starting up the app, and after a few seconds it should disappear, and the background shows till the user close down the app. 
The source I provided is just one of the things I've tried, which is detecting the screen size, and if portrait then it'll use the code I provided here. I haven't made for landscape, as I didn't want to go further without the other to work first.

Comment: As mentioned, if I have the TImage as align:=client and wrapmode:=center, then it misplaces the images, but not on other forms.
I'm starting to think that it might be some memory issues of some kind, or maybe more that it's limitations for android that I don't know about, because it's working fine on win32+64 when I compile as such.
I really hope someone can help me out, because I'm starting to lose my mind here :-)

Comment: Ok, well I was thinking about the resolution, as the source image is 2160 x 2160. The easy solution is to stretch as needed to fit the display, but will change the looks of the text. Is that OK? Is it irrelevant if the aspect ratio changes according to the physical display?Any other requirements, that you haven't said yet?

Comment: I want to keep the proportions. Which is why I tried cropping upon startup, and then stretch, so I'd make sure that it's the same aspect ratio.
But I somehow feel like it's a work around, instead of fixing/taking care of the real problem.

Comment: Ok, I think I know enough now, I will return after some time with a solution for a vertical display.

Comment: Thanks, it means a lot to me :-)

Comment: Also, how does everyone else make a splash screen on their apps?
Now I tried using 2 forms, and upon start, it shows Form2, then start a timer, which then makes Form2 to disappear again, but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close, I think the following peculiarity in the Delphi code probably gave you most headache:

In your code you have something like this:

```
iRect.Width := ...
iRect.Height := ...
iRect.Left := ...
iRect.Top := ...
```

A `TRect` (or `TRectF`) is determined by its four properties: `Left, Top, Right, Bottom`. 
When you change the dimensions using `width` (and `height`), you call this setter procedure:

```
// This is the code in XE7, I do not know if it has been changed later
procedure TRect.SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
  Self.Right := Self.Left + Value;
end;
```

`SetHeight` is very similar.

When you change `Left` or `Top` the corresponding fields are simply changed, but not `Right` nor `Bottom`. The result is that the `width` or `height` also changes.

Imagine a local uninitialized variable `iRect`, that might have whatever values for `Left` and `Right`. Your code above may end up with very strange `TRect` rectangles. The fix is to set `Left` and `Top` properties first, then either `Right` and `Top` or `Width` and `Height`.

To show the image, you required it to follow aspect ratio, which means that slices need to be cut away from the sides of the image when showing it vertically (and from top and bottom when showing it horizontally). I made this with `iRect` so that it is initialized to the size of the screen, and then offset with half the difference between screen size and image size.

Here is code to show the image according to screen size. Here is only vertical display, but horizontal would follow same scheme. For brevity I also did not include the splash image, use the same code and your own change logic. The comments in the code should explain my toughts. As you see it is largely very similar as yours, your calculations of `iRect.Width` and `iRect.Left` were not right, probably because of the `TRect` peculiarity.

```
// I feel more comfortable with a bmp as temporary storage than the TImage, therefore this minor mod
procedure Load_Bitmap_From_Resource(var bmp: TBitmap; res_name: String);
var InStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  InStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, res_name, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Bmp.LoadFromStream(InStream);
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScrHeight, ScrWidth: integer;
  bmp, bmp2, BmpSplash: TBitmap;
  iRect: TRect;
begin
  // Form1 acted for me also as a simulation form during dev, therefore
  // these settings are not meant to be included in actual application
  // ***********
  self.Left := 0; self.ClientWidth  := 270;
  self.Top  := 0; self.ClientHeight := 540;
  // ***********

  // Use FireMonkey Platform Services, IFMXScreeService to get real size of screen
  ScrHeight := 2160; // just arbitrary examples, ..
  ScrWidth  := 1080; // ..for testing use size of your own phone

  // I feel more comfortable with a bmp as temporary storage than the TImage
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Load_Bitmap_From_Resource(bmp, '0_bg');

    iRect := Rect(Point(0, 0), Point(ScrWidth, ScrHeight));
    iRect.Offset((bmp.Width-ScrWidth) div 2, (bmp.Height-ScrHeight) div 2);

    bmp2 := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bmp2.SetSize(iRect.Width, iRect.Height);
      bmp2.CopyFromBitmap(bmp, iRect, 0, 0);
      Form1.Image_bg.Bitmap.Assign(bmp2);
      Form1.Image_bg.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    finally
      bmp2.DisposeOf;
    end;
  finally
    bmp.DisposeOf;
  end;

  Form1.Image_bg.Visible := True;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I just tried it on the example/replicated code I made, and it did indeed work. So now I'm currently trying to implement it into my app, then I'll get back to you if it works ;-)

Comment: False alarm.. It worked on Memu emulator, then I tried implement it on my app, but then I compiled and tried that in Memu as well, and then it froze some of the procedures. I then tried on my phone, and then it wouldn't even install. "App not installed." , it says.
Then I tried install the test app that I made, with your code, on my phone, but that wouldn't install either, as it gave me the same message.

Comment: Is there something I need to do in order to compile Android apps properly? I'm starting to think that the compiler or something else might be the issue, because I don't get that it's supposed to be that fragile.
Delphi never been this unstable, of what I've tried. :-/

Comment: Please note that SO is a q/a site where specific questions are answered. It is not an ongoing debugging service. Your specific question was how to fix your code to show a background image and a splash image correctly instead of the erroneously cropped images that you showed in your question. I pointed out the errors you had in your code, showed you the fix and provided sample code. Therefore I think I have answered your specific question. If you can point out that there is an error in my answer, I will be the first to be willing to make a correction.

Comment: The fact that you cannot get your program to work is a totally different matter and I have no possibilities to know, or even guess, what else might be wrong in your code (mind you, I have only seen the code you have shown). Thus I can not possible have any idea of what else you should fix, sorry. You need to do some debugging and come back with new questions if needed.

Comment: I finally got it to work. And I know this isn't a debugging service, I just got frustrated in the process, and I'm sorry about that. 
I now use the code that you provided, and it seems to do the trick, I cannot thank you enough for you help and time. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm glad that you got it sorted out. Here at SO we show our appreciation of both questions and answers by upvoting (click the up arrow beside the q or a). Or, if the q or a is not usefull, by downvoting using the down arrow. In addition, if the asker evaluates an answer to be correct they can click on the tick mark beside the answer, so it turns green. It is explained in detail on [this page in the help system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I marked your answer as green now, and upvoted it as well, but since I have less than 15 reputation, it isn't public, it says.